Requesting Assistance with a PowerShell Script to read an attribute
I have a PowerShell Script that reads our Active Directory and writes the "extensionAttribute2, EmailAddress, sAMAccountName, UserPrincipalName and proxyaddresses" attributes to a CSV file.  Here is the primary portion of the code:
Get-ADUser -SearchBase "something here" -Filter * -Properties extensionAttribute2, EmailAddress, sAMAccountName, UserPrincipalName, proxyaddresses | 
Select-Object extensionAttribute2, EmailAddress, sAMAccountName, UserPrincipalName, @{L = "ProxyAddresses"; E = { ($_.ProxyAddresses -match '^SMTP:') -join ";"}}|Sort ProxyAddresses -descending | Export-CSV -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation 

Because each user account has two proxy accounts (that's another issue for a different time), I want only to show users who meet the following criteria:
'SMTP:username@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com'

I have tried various formats of the code but have been unable to retrieve the code with only the users meeting the SMTP criteria.  Could you please tell me how to properly code this?
Thank you.

"I want only to show users who meet the following criteria", what is the criteria? You want to find all users having the primary SMTP domain as domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com ? Please clarify

What are you expecting your output to look like? (It's not clear to me from your question)

Sorry for the lack of clarity.  I want the output of the CSV file to show users in AD who have the proxyaddress attribute of SMTP:username@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com and not those who have the proxyaddress atrribute of  smtp:username@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com. (A difference in the letter case of the SMTP).  I hope that helps.

What you're looking for is -cmatch instead of -match, the PowerShell operators starting with the c prefix are all case-sensitive. As aside, the -join ';' might not be needed (leave it for you to test) since user's should have only one primary SMTP address (uppercase SMTP:), meaning, the result from the expression $_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP:' should be a single string.
$getADUserSplat = @{
    SearchBase = 'something here'
    LDAPFilter = '(proxyAddresses=SMTP:*@domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com)'
    Properties = 'extensionAttribute2', 'EmailAddress', 'sAMAccountName', 'UserPrincipalName', 'proxyaddresses'
}

Get-ADUser @getADUserSplat |
    Select-Object @(
        'extensionAttribute2'
        'EmailAddress'
        'sAMAccountName'
        'UserPrincipalName'
        @{ L='ProxyAddresses'; E={ ($_.ProxyAddresses -cmatch '^SMTP:') -join ';' }}) |
    Sort-Object ProxyAddresses -Descending |
    Export-Csv -Path $Output -NoTypeInformation


Excellent!  Thank you that worked perfect.

@talway glad it helped. please accept the answer if this solved the issue
